# DB2 for IBM i (AS400) query substr

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have 48/50 g in a as400 database and I want to (query)substr before the "/" and before the space between 50 and g.

Result I should get is 50

I'm searching for hours now and try and try but no luck.

any help is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `POSITION` to find the '/' and space characters. e.g. `POSITION(FIELDA, '/')` will return the position of the '/' character. You can then use these positions to build the appropriate `SUBSTRING` statement.

Comment: 'AS/400' is an obsolete name.  The current name is IBM i and that will help when searching for current information.  The IBM i Knowledge Center is at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i/welcome   Here is the 7.2 SQL Reference: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzintro.htm

Comment: Thank you Buck, you absolutly right, I'm so old school!

Comment: I read recently in the Memo To Users (MTU) (http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzaq9/rzaq9.pdf) that the `POSITION` scalar will be *corrected* with the DB2 for IBM i SQL in IBM i 7.2 to effect DB2 parity; for the comma-delimited-arguments syntax, the search-string and source-string will switch to be in that order, a reverse from prior releases. No idea why there are no change-flags: [for 7.2](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzscaposition.htm) [for 7.1](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzscaposition.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the LOCATE() function...
Assuming that the first space is the one you want the following will work:

```
--create variable mystr char(10) default('48/50 g') 
select substr(mystr                 
              , locate('/'          
                       , mystr) + 1 
              , locate(' '          
                       , mystr)     
                 - (locate('/'       
                           , mystr) + 1)  
              )                     
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

However, if this is an often needed function.  Consider creating a user defined function (UDF) that will parse and split the string in this manner.

Comment: A minor edit adding "- 1" after the last LOCATE() might be needed. As coded, the result is three characters "50_" including trailing blank. Otherwise, this is good.

Comment: I just realize that I have two space in the string, one at the beginning and the one between after 50 and G. How can I remove the first space so the locate and substring will work?

Comment: Instead using only a space in [the LOCATE() function](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzscalocate.htm?lang=en), you could use **" g"**. Adding the "g" to the _search-substring_ might be enough to make it recognize which space you want. Or you could use the _start-position_ parameter to tell LOCATE() where to start searching. You'd copy the LOCATE('/'...) function to that parameter because that's where you want it to begin searching.