# C# .Net OleDbCommand with SQL request using "substring" word not working with DB2/400 database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, db2-400, oledbcommand

I'm working on Rest API that uses a DB2/400 database ( IBMi ).

I'm using this string to connect to database:

```
//  Defaut connexion string           
ConnectString = "Provider=IBMDA400;" + "Password=xxxxxxx;" +"User ID=Bxxxxxxxx;" +"Data Source=XXX.XX.XX.XX;";
```

The connection to the system is working well :

```
ConnectLst = new OleDbConnection(ConnectString);
try
{
    ConnectLst = new OleDbConnection(ConnectString);

    ConnectLst.Open();

    ResCnx = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ResCnx = false;
}

finally
{ }

return ResCnx;
```

My problem is that a simple SQL request with a substring doesn't works:

```
string W_RqtSql = "SELECT SUBSTRING(CDMATN,2,3) " +                
                 " FROM " + @_Schema + ".CSALAR CSAL " +                     
                 " where CSAL.NOPPHN = '" + @_NumPers + "'";
```

I have the following error message :

- `$exception {"SQL0104: Syntactic element ,2 is not correct. Possible elements: , FROM.\r\nCause . . . . .: A syntax error was detected at element ,2. , 2 is not a valid element. , FROM is a partial list of valid elements.`

I have also tried `SUBSTR`, but doesn't work either.

The same SQL request without "substring" word works very well :

```
string W_RqtSql = "SELECT CDMATN " +                
                 " FROM " + @_Schema + ".CSALAR CSAL " +                     
                 " where CSAL.NOPPHN = '" + @_NumPers + "'";
```

How can I select a substring of my column value?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but **warning: your code is open to *SQL Injection Attacks***.  Rather than embedding parameter values in query strings, you should **always** construct parameterized queries.  See: [How do parameterized queries help against SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5468425/3744182) and [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7505808/3744182).

Comment: Also not an answer, but is there any reason you could not do the substring on the C# side after fetching values from the database?  For instance are the strings in the DB extremely long, so you would like to extract the substring before sending them to your REST code?

Comment: I don't know DB2/400 at all, but [DB2 for IBM i (AS400) query substr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28180743) shows the substring function name as **`substr`** not `SUBSTRING`.  This [doc page](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/13?topic=functions-substr) from IBM also shows `SUBSTR`.  So you might give that a try.

Comment: Yes, you're right : i will adapt my code against sql injection.

I need to substring in SQL command because in the final SQL request, i have to make sub-request with the value returned by the substring.

Comment: Yes, I have already try "SUBSTR", but doesn't work too. It's very strange problem : the request is very simple !

Comment: Is it possible that it's a bug of  OleDbConnection ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know whether `OleDbConnection` parses the SQL itself or just passes it on to the database.  How is the column `CDMATN` defined?  Also, might you please [edit] your question to include the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s), if any?

Comment: The CDMATN column is string.
Ok, thanks, don't worry :)

Comment: According to the [docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/13?topic=columns-string-data-types) DB2 supports several types of string.  Can you share exactly how `CDMATN` is defined?

Comment: maybe some values length is less than 2? so, 2 is not valid?

Comment: CDMATN : CHARACTER
LENGTH : 5

Comment: Try with spaces between commas and numbers like this : `SUBSTRING(CDMATN, 2, 3)`

Comment: @nfgl : Thanks so much !! 

It's working now !!     :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is :

syntaxe with spaces between commas and numbers like this : SUBSTRING(CDMATN, 2, 3)

Many thanks for your help :)